# Enums in Processing 1.2.1?

Tags: enums, processing

Here is my sketch:

```java
enum Foo { bar, baz }

void setup() { }
void draw() { }
```

This fails to compile:

```java
Unrecognized type:46 (ENUM_DEF)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or are enums not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they aren't supported unfortunately, but there are some workarounds. From the [FAQ](http://wiki.processing.org/w/FAQ#I_know_Java.2C_is_this_Java.3F_How_do_I_use_it_that_way.3F):

> We currently only support Java 1.4
>   (and earlier) syntax. You cannot
>   currently use 1.5 syntax in the
>   Processing Development Environment.
>   This means no generics, templates,
>   enum, varargs, foreach, and the rest.
>   If you want to use Java 1.5 (or
>   later), **take core.jar and develop your
>   project with another Java IDE**

If you're comfortable with Java, you can always base your project in Java and access the Processing code via traditional Java classes.  The [FAQ](http://wiki.processing.org/w/FAQ#I_know_Java.2C_is_this_Java.3F_How_do_I_use_it_that_way.3F) has some pointers on that too.